# Simplify Retrieving Input Into Array

Tags: c#, asp.net, coding-style

```
private bool[] Question = new bool[59];
//Question[0] = Placeholder
if (Q1.Value == "yes") Question[1] = true;
else Question[1] = false;

if (Q2.Value == "yes") Question[2] = true;
else Question[2] = false;

if (Q3.Value == "yes") Question[3] = true;
else Question[3] = false;

if (Q4.Value == "yes") Question[4] = true;
else Question[4] = false;

if (Q5.Value == "yes") Question[5] = true;
else Question[5] = false;
```

I have 58 of these, following the same pattern. Q1, Q2, Q3, etc. are HTML elements. I know how to use a for loop using Question[i] but Q[i].Value would not work. I think I could make a List of HTML elements and then iterate through them alongside the array but I was curious if there is another accepted method for accomplishing this task, before I rewrite all this code. Thank you in advance for your opinion and explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Creating a collection of HTML controls then iterating through them would be the best approach. This way you can use the collection for more things in the future. Use a `List<T>` so you can have better control and easier navigation.

Comment: I had `List<T>` above but SO reformatted it. Would I set my List to type 'HtmlInputHidden' or is there a type that accepts all Html controls?

Comment: @Zerkey - HtmlInputHidden inherits from HtmlInputControl which in turn inherits from HtmlControl. So you can use either depending on what you want to accomplish.